# How to validate dojo TextBox based on regEx after completion of typing

Tags: regex, textbox, dojo

I have a use case where I need to match a string based on a regEx.
The input is in a dojo ValidationTextBox where I have to add regEx to match a particular string.
The string to be matched is for bandwidths. For eg: 100 Mbps, 1 Gbps, 10 Kbps, etc.
This regex works: `[1-9][0-9]*[ ][M|K|G|T][b][p][s]`

However, the validation textbox throws error as and when I start typing since the String is not yet complete.
Supposing, the value i want to add is "100 Mbps", the moment I enter '1', the error is shown since the regEx is not matched.

How can I make the textBox validate after I finish typing?.

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using and what browser? I tried your example and it didn't give me any error at all (unless I typed something like 'jsldk' which could never match **OR** when I leave the textbox). I even made a JSFiddle to test it out http://jsfiddle.net/axjPB/

Comment: Dojo Version is 1.7. Any Browser.

Comment: Any way, this might be because of an overlying library that i am using on top of dojo. There was one API for validating subsets, and i put my logic there and it works now. "_isValidSubset" - not sure if is in dojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used to use our own library on top Dojo. We found a solution by checking whether the entered string was a substring of the regex (starting from the left most) each time the user entered some character and once the focus is removed, we check the whole string with the regex.

Answer (score -1):

You are finished typing once the final 'bps' has been input. I would first check that the last 3 chars (get the substring) are in fact 'bps' before running the regex.

Comment: There is one more criteria. If i enter some invalid String, say #$%^%", it should throw the invalid error immediately. If i wait until 'bps', i might have as well entered "@#@#@ bps", which will eventually fail, but I wont be notified immediately